# boost geometry point setter and getter

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I'm working with the boost geometry library and i have read in the documentation that i should  prefer using `boost::geometry::set<0>(point1, 1.0);` instead of `point1.set<0>(1.0);`
Same with the get method: `bg::get<0>(point1)` instead of `point1.get<0>();`

Can anyone explain why i should do so? The documentation is here (Examples; on the bottom of the page): [boost point documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/models/model_point.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using boost::geometry::get<0>(point1) you support any point type. Also points having methods like point.x(). Using point1.get<0>() you support only some point types, like the point type provided by Boost.Geometry. However, if that is all you need, you can use that of course too.